# Add a img and setTimeout after losing focus from input

Tags: jquery

follows the example below:

```
<tr>
    <td  width='75px' class='someClass'>
         <input class='input'  type='text' size='5'/>
    </td>
    <td width='75px'class='someClass'>some value</td>
</tr>
```

i have 10 rows of the code above, so this is simple:

when i lose focus from input, i have to create a img beside the input and then set a timeOut to that img just fadeOut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how to do this:

```
$('input.input').live('blur', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $img = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://placekitten.com/70/70');
    $this.after($img);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.next('img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fBfV4/1/

Comment: perfect ( except for the little cat ). ty!

Comment: @ric_bfa: You're welcome, and I think you should keep the kitten there.

Comment: hey, one problem, if i change to fast from a input to another, he add 2 img's besid the input.. what can i do ?

Comment: problem solved, forgot to put the remove in the fadeOut call back, ty again.

Answer (score 1):

I ... think I understand what you're after.  This should come close:

```
$('td.someClass input').blur(function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.parent().append('<img src="" />');

  setTimeout(function () {
    $this.next('img').remove();
  }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.input').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).after('<img src="src.jpg" />');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).next('img').fadeOut('slow'), 1000);
});
```

This will append an image after the input field, and then start the fadeout after the specified interval.

Comment: Sorry, -1, questioner talks about focus loss but you're using `mouseout`. Also, there's a syntax error in the callback passed to `setTimeout()`. Please consider improving your answer.